# Running chromium with multiple data-dir using desktop files on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: snap, chromium, .desktop

I want to create the following configuration, which work for me well on ubuntu 18.04:
Run two (or more) different instances of chromium, each with different configuration, and using separate icons on the dock panel.

On ubuntu 18.04 the .desktop files look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=WhatsApp Web
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/ --user-data-dir=/home/tamar/.config/.whatsapp
Icon=/home/tamar/.local/share/icons/personal/whatsapp.png
StartupWMClass=web.whatsapp.com
X-GNOME-SingleWindow=true
```

Another file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Proxy
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/home/tamar/.config/.proxy --proxy-server=socks5://localhost:8888
X-GNOME-SingleWindow=true
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 the same configuration doesn't work.
I've read that since it's a snap installation I have to run chromium with the command line:
`snap run chromium --user-data-dir=.whatever`

When running it from command line it seems to work (at least most of the time ...), but when calling it with .desktop file it seems to use the same profile configuration for both: opening new tab on the web application opens on the opened "with proxy" window, and the IP is the proxies' one instead of the computer's IP

Is there any solution that uses the chromium instance installed with Ubuntu 20.04 package?

Answer (score 0):

The snap Chromium process, running in strict confinement mode, cannot read or write to all subdirectories in your home directory. For example:

- it can read the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file on launch to locate the user's Download directory;
- it can't, though, write to `~/.config/` to create a `~/.config/my-app/` data directory; but
- it **can** write to `~/` to create a `~/my-app/` data directory and its contents.

If you open the WhatsApp .desktop file that you used as an example with `gtk-launch` in the command line:

```sh
$ gtk-launch ~/.local/share/applications/whatsapp.desktop
```

You should get an error message like this:

> Failed to create data directory - Chromium cannot read and write its
> data directory: /home/tamar/.config/.whatsapp

To get an app directory that is hidden from view in home you'll need to put it in `~/snap/chromium/common/<appname>`. Using your example, the line in the .desktop file would be:

```
Exec=/snap/bin/chromium --user-data-dir=snap/chromium/common/whatsapp --class=whatsapp --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
StartupWMClass=whatsapp
```